# SpringBoot - Gradle - MYSQL Connector with MIT/Apache License

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mysql-connector

Hi as part of our product development we are using JAVA spring boot - Gradle - MySQL Connector/J 8.0 to connect our MYSQL database But this is  General Public License (GPLv2) license. Is there any MY SQL connector available with MIT/Apache License ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a LGPL license, the closest to a MIT/Apache license in v8.0.29, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.29, and below but they moved to a GPL license in mysql.connector.j v8.0.30.  Would love it if Spring-boot had stayed with the LGPL version as they updated their versions.  Oracle also licenses if your company doesn't like GPL.